# Kotlin: createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying dynamically set a text to the layout.

Example code:
Start.kt:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.basic.databinding.StartBinding

class Start : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding : StartBinding = setContentView(MainActivity(), R.layout.start)
        binding.textView.setText("Hello World")
    }

}
```

start.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Start">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Current GPS Location"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
...
```

Gradle build ends ok but application crashes with this error when I open this page at my mobile phone:

```
[qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

How to repair it?

Comment: This is not correct way for creating `val binding : StartBinding = setContentView(MainActivity(), R.layout.start)`, You should try `val binding : StartBinding = StartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`

Comment: Yes, thank you! My application works but it looks like `setText` doesn't work. Do you know why? Name of the layout is `start.xml` and name of the script and the class is `Start`.

Comment: Well if you can paste your activity and XML code, we will be able to figure out issue

Comment: Not in the comment, it's not readable, edit your question and add the code to it

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Frgment Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

to understand how a fragment works

Refer to this for [View Binding](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6430697-view-binding-tutorial-for-android-getting-started)

For Kotlin refer to [Kotlin Offical Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/)

To set fragment view Fragment override the `onCreateView` and then update ui for initial state in `onViewCreated` callback.

```
class Start : Fragment() {

        lateinit var binding : StartBinding

     override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding  = StartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false) 
        return binding.root
    }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.textView.setText("Hello World")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! But `Fragment Tutorial` works with `findViewById`. `View Binding` looks right but there is not using `setText`. There's only `setContentView`. So I tried replace `setContentView` by `setText`. WIthout success. I'm using `Log.d` to check a run of the code in `onCreateView` - it looks ok. So I don't know why setText not works.

Comment: `setContentView` is to set the view that to be shown in the activity window, whereas `setText` is a method in `TextView` class, to set the `text` shown on that, @djlj be a little specific about what you want to do

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand. It does other thing. So I still don't know how to use setText .

Comment: basically you can call `setText` on any view provided by android, if it is a child of  `TextView` class(Pure java concept), unless that particular class overrides it and makes it private

Comment: What must be in import? I'm looking at the internet. Examples contains often this: `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` and `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`. But my Android Studio shows `v7` and `android` in red color.

Comment: I'm reading all manuals and trying... It's better - build is without error. But setText still not works. `binding = StartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater); binding.location.setText("Hello World")` not works. I tried also `binding.location.text("Hello World")` - not works.

Comment: @djlj it was a bug, I have fixed, check now

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is ok, but page "Start" crashes .

```
get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.basic, PID: 13619
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
        at com.example.basic.Start.onViewCreated(Start.kt:56)
```

Line 56 is this: `binding.textView.setText("Hello World")`

So... I'm going to read tutorials which you linked here.

Comment: remove this from the answers and edit your question instead, putting an issue or code related to your issue in the answer section is misleading, and paste your complete code for that view, how you are initializing the binding, your layout file too, to know if you are using `viewbinding` or `databinding`